# How do I get the color on my monitor to print that same color

Tags: color

I am having a very hard time trying to get the color turquoise . When converting from rgb to cmyk they are nothing close. How do I get the color of turquoise I see on my monitor to be printed on cards? What is the best method to see the conversion on my monitor?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's what happens when you convert the brightest of RGB blues (#00ffff) to CMYK for printing.  The dramatic change is because it's outside the CMYK colour gamut - in essence that means it's an unprintable colour. So the short answer to your question is it's not possible to get the bright turquoise you see on screen to print on a card.

You'll need to choose another CMYK colour that's closer, but there is no way that it will ever be as vivid as a pure RGB #00ffff, because there is no ink on this planet that is as bright turquoise as that.

The brightest most vivid blue available in CMYK is probably 100% Cyan - but pure cyan is darker than RGB #00ffff - you could lighten it by using less cyan and a touch of yellow.